# I cannot convert c++ to java

Tags: java, c++

How can I convert this C++ code to Java?
I could not convert parameter &poly_size in method clip.
This code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polygon-clipping-sutherland-hodgman-algorithm-please-change-bmp-images-jpeg-png/

```
void suthHodgClip(int poly_points[][2], int poly_size, int clipper_points[][2], int clipper_size) 
{ 
    for (int i=0; i<clipper_size; i++) 
    { 
        int k = (i+1) % clipper_size; 
        clip(poly_points, poly_size, clipper_points[i][0], clipper_points[i][1], clipper_points[k][0], clipper_points[k][1]); 
    } 

}

void clip(int poly_points[][2], int &poly_size, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
{ 
    int new_points[MAX_POINTS][2], new_poly_size = 0; 

    // blabla 

    poly_size = new_poly_size; 
    for (int i = 0; i < poly_size; i++) 
    { 
        poly_points[i][0] = new_points[i][0]; 
        poly_points[i][1] = new_points[i][1]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Learn `java` and use the same logic to write code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remember that Java isn't C++, so odds are a direct translation is going to be sub-optimal.

With that out of the way, The question is *How do you pass an integer by reference in Java?* The only reason in C++ you would pass `poly_size` by reference is if you wanted to change its value inside the function, and that happens at `poly_size = new_poly_size;`

My Java is tragically rusty, but I'd take advantage of the C++ version of `clip` not returning anything and make the Java version `return new_poly_size;`

Comment: this is not a software conversion service

Comment: @gpasch nor is it a lot of things, but it does seem a reasonable place to point out to someone that they don't want to convert the code in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't give you choice over pass-by-value and pass-by-reference. Instead it passes primitives, such as `int` by value, and objects by reference.

Unfortunately the Java non-primitive `Integer` (which would be passed by reference) is immutable, so the only ways of doing this would be to either return `new_poly_size`, or make your own modifiable object containing this value, pass it to the function.

Comment: Integer in Java is immutable, so it can't be modified.

Comment: Java doesn’t actually pass anything by reference.  It passes parameters which contain references (roughly the same as pointers), but changing the value of an object parameter itself inside a method will never change the variable that the caller passed as that parameter.

Comment: But you could also describe that as 'passing the object by reference' which is not the same thing as 'passing the variable by reference'.  Assignment assigns a reference to a variable; parameter passing assigns a reference to the formal parameter.

Comment: this is not a software conversion service